# Convert RGB-image to one-channel gray image in R EBImage

Tags: r, image-processing

An R-beginner question:

I wanted to convert an RGB-Image to grayscale and display/plot it with image()

```
library(EBImage)
orig = readImage("c:/test/b/s2.png")
gray = orig
colorMode(gray) = Grayscale

display(gray) #works
image(gray) #Error 'z' should be a matrix
```

The image converted by colorMode(gray) = Grayscale seems to be incompatible with image-function. Does Crayscale image in R EBImage has more than one channel?

Then I converted it manually and was able to call image() on it

```
r = channel(orig,"r")
g = channel(orig,"g")
b = channel(orig,"b")

gray1 = 0.21*r+0.71*g+0.07*b

display(gray1) 
image(gray1) #works
```

However, the images both gray differed slightly concerning intensity.
Is there a way to convert RGB to one channel gray in R EBImage?

**EDIT**
For answering the question, why EBImage:

The package provides some image-processing functions. E.g. I could display easily the intensity graph (img2) of a scanned test-stripe (img1) using further EBImage commands:

```
blotgraph = resize(gblur(gray1,3),200,1)
plot(blotgraph, type="l")
```

I was not aware how to solve such kind of tasks without EBImage

[image: img1]
[image: img2]

Comment: In the code you've posted you've made a mistake in the first block. Should be `image(gray)` not `image(grey)`?

Comment: Why do you want to use `EBImage` ?  Converting image objects to grayscale is not a big deal with the standard `base` and `graphics` package tools.

Comment: @Manetheran OK, thanks! I've fixed. However it has of cause not solved the problem :-).

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: I came to R more or less accidentally. I've googled for some image-processing related issues and came across EBImage. I've tried R and loved it instantly. So you would suggest to try implementing everything with core-functions first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry if I am wrong, but as I understand your conversion to greyscale is not being done in a proper way. In general with EBImage conversion to grayscale is done with the command `grayimage<-channel(yourimage,"gray")`
and image(grayimage) gives

```
Image
  colormode: Grayscale 
  storage.mode: double 
  dim: X Y 
  nb.total.frames: 1 
  nb.render.frames: 1
```

where the colormode gives the `nb.total.frames:3`

Comment: Perfect! That's what I've been looking for. (I think you've meant nb.total.frames:1 not 3) I was not aware of "gray" parameter-value for channel-function

Answer (score 7):

This might be simpler, though there are faster and cleaner ways to compress the color layers.

```
library(png)
foo<-readPNG("c:/test/b/s2.png")
#that's an array n by m by 3 . Now reduce to grey
bar<- foo[,,1]+foo[,,2]+foo[,,3]
# normalize
bar <- bar/max(bar)
# one of many ways to plot
plot(c(0,1),c(0,1),t='n')
rasterImage(bar, 0,0,1,1)
```

Note that this has created a greyscale image object `bar` while 'saving' the full-color object `foo` .

Comment: Interesting to learn png-package! bar<- foo[,,1]+foo[,,2]+foo[,,3] without factors? If you've just leaved the factors for the sake of example-simplicity, then it is the same as: gray1 = 0.21*channel(orig,"r")+0.71*channel(orig,"g")+0.07*channel(orig,"b"). I thought, there is an explicit command for rgb to gray 8-bit conversion. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz there must be an rgb--to--gray function somewhere,but I can't find it just now :-(